# iptables geoip exclude single IP from blocked country

Tags: iptables, geoip

I'm using iptables 1.4.21 with xtables-addons to block IPs per country.
Now I want to exclude one or more IPs from blocked country but can't..

I tried

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xxxxxx -j ACCEPT
```

but don't work

is it possible to exclude IPs when using "-m geoip --src-cc" ?

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I found I needed to INSERT instead of APPENDING

```
  iptables -I INPUT -s xxxxxxxx -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Yes; iptables rules are processed in order, and the first matching rule with a builtin target (`ACCEPT` or `DROP`) will decide the fate of the packet and end rule processing for that packet. Iptables extensions may add other process-ending targets, like `REJECT`. So, to add an exception for an existing rule, insert a new rule for the desired exception *before* the existing rule. This applies to all of iptables, not just geoip.